# rule of thumb for new and delete

Tags: c++

I was wondering what the rule of thumb for `new` and `delete` is. 
I always thought that every time I call `new`, I should have a `delete`.

In the case below, if I include the `destructor` however, I get a bad
excess error. If I don't include the `destructor`, my code works fine.

```
struct Foo
 {
     Foo(int A, int B)
     {
          bar = new std::vector< std::vector < int > >(A, std::vector<int>(B,2);
          //creates a vector of A vectors where each nested vector contains the number 2 B times. 
     }

     ~Foo() //Get bad access error if destructor included in code. 
     {
          delete[] bar;
     }     

     std::vector< std::vector < int > > *bar;
 };

int main()
{
    Foo X;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You're using `delete[]` but there isn't an array. Why are you using `new` with a vector anyway?

Comment: go through this link http://www.parashift.com/c%2B%2B-faq-lite/freestore-mgmt.html

Comment: And you also need to define a copy constructor to make sure that copies have their own memory to subsequently `delete`.

Comment: Hi @Rapptz, in my code, `bar` is a vector of vector of object `MyObj` with a non-trivial constructor. So I thought that to initialize it, I would need something like 

`bar = new std::vector< std::vector < MyObj > >(A, std::vector< MyObj >(B, MyObj(int a, int b) );`

sorry, I should of made this more clear.

Comment: @Keith, Don't forget a copy assignment operator.

Comment: You have a `new` but no `delete`, breaking your own rule. You should use `delete[]` with `new[]`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is The Rule of Three?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4172722/what-is-the-rule-of-three)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It should be `delete bar;` not `delete [] bar;`

Add another rule to your list of rules.

> The delete line should have a [] only if the new line has a [some number]

In your case the `new` line does not have a `[some number]`

```
 bar = new std::vector< std::vector < int > >(A, std::vector<int>(B,2);
```

So your delete line also should not have one.

Comment: I'd like to clarify, since when you look at it the right way, the answer could suggest that `delete` does the job in both cases (not that I'm saying you intended it to), that all `new`s should only be matched with `delete`s, and all `new[]`s should only be matched with `delete[]`s.

Comment: The rule you cite is overly simplistic, and it's easy to find cases where it doesn't apply.  (Think of typedefs.  A allocating a pointer to a function.)  The real rule is to determine exactly the type you are allocating, and if it is an array, use `std::vector`, rather than `new[]`.

Answer (score 6):

The above class might be better written as:

```
struct Foo   
 {
     Foo(int A, int B)
       :  bar(A, std::vector<int>(B,2)) //creates a vector of A vectors where each nested vector contains the number 2 B times. 
     {}
     // Default copy
     // Default destructor.

     std::vector< std::vector < int > > bar;
 };
```

This avoids explicit `new` and `delete`; often the best `rule of thumb` for using them correctly!

Answer (score 0):

With unmanaged code like c++ the rule of thumb is whatever is required by your design.

In general, it's a good idea to clean up your objects to avoid memory leaks, but you could have a situation where you want to keep something in memory.